# SQL count occurence of having count > 2 with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, having

I need to count the occurrence of the same value in a table over multiple rows.

as an example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ca74/13

there is a table with a multi column primary key (column A | column B).

```
(fID_a)    |   type
1          |   'type A'
1          |   'type B'
2          |   'type A'
3          |   'type B'
3          |   'type D'
...
9          |   'type A'
9          |   'type B'
```

how do I count the occurrence of all types combined

expected result for the above example

```
type            |     count
'type A'        |     1
'type A type B' |     2
'type B type D' |     1
```

this works only for a single occurrence in column A

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count, 
       type 
FROM   tbl_a 
WHERE  fid_a IN (SELECT fid_a 
                 FROM   tbl_a 
                 GROUP  BY fid_a 
                 HAVING Count(*) = 1) 
GROUP  BY tbl_a.type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using string aggregation to combine them for each `fID_a` value and then aggregate on that result.  This is a bit of a pain in SQL Server, but possible:

```
select types, count(*), min(fID_a), max(fID_a)
from (select fID_a,
             stuff((select ',' + type
                    from tbl_a a2
                    where a2.fID_a = a.fID_a
                    order by type
                    for xml path ('')
                   ), 1, 1, '') as types
      from tbl_a a
      group by fID_a
     ) t
group by types;
```

I added in the minimum and maximum of the other `id` so you can double check the results.

Comment: +1 I think you should also add `ORDER BY type` before `FOR XML PATH` to prevent `AB` - `BA` separation.

Comment: `order by` needs to be added right after the where clause to work